# iPad Crashes when iPhone 3G and iPhone4 does not

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I think this is a memory issue, but i'm unsure on what to do here.

My issue:

I've nearly finished a game using cocos2d for the iphone, with retina gfx, I've made the app universal, and have done adjustments to make it run correctly on the iPad, mostly I use the retina spritesheets on the ipad, with a few additional images (contained inside the -hd spritesheets) to cover the edges of the screen etc.

Everything is working fine, the iPad, when in the game runs at 60fps, like on the iphone4 (i usually get about 40-50fps on iphone3g), however, occasionally, after 5 minutes or so of moving between menus on the iPad (generally, but not always, after unloading the game engine and moving back to the menus), the game falls over.

In the debugger, i get 'Received memory warning.', shortly after (not immediately), when a new spritesheet or graphic is loaded (not creation of a sprite, but the actually loading of a new texture into memory), the app closes and all that I get in the console is '(gdb)' with no stacktrace.

I'm struggling to find a solution, when moving from my game engine to my menus, I have a loading screen, which is mostly created using 1 full screen image, and some text, all other textures, spriteframes and preloaded soundfx are then purged from memory before anything new is loaded in.

I've attempted to run the ipad with leaks and allocations on in instruments, but as soon as the app loads, instruments crashes every time.

Does anyone happen to know what the max memory space is for an ipad app before it closes (i thought i'd atleast get 3 warnings, not 1), and how many 2048 x 2048 sheets does that equate too?

EDIT: (New cause of irrational memory disappearance discovered!)

So, weeks later, I stumble onto this post on the cocos2d forums.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/31092

This bug in iOS5 is likely to be the main cause of my troubles, all advice and suggestions have helped, in my opinion, to tighten up my app as a whole.

Comment: Did you enable NSZombieEnabled for the executable ? http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled

Comment: Doesn't the crash log tell you anything ?

Comment: there is no a fixed amount of memory you can rely on, the os kills your app if you are using more memory than the os can free for you. the ipad if i remember correctly has half the memory of the iphone4, and you are using the same big images.. can be that you are leaking something. you can load many 2048x2048 sheets without major problems

Comment: I currently have NSZombieEnabled off, the game is not crashing due to a message being sent to a deallocated instance, (i've checked on ipad, iphone3g and iphone4) it only crashes on iPad after receiving a memory warning

Comment: Nothing in the crash log at all Paul

Comment: I have ran my application in leaks on the iPhone4 for up to an hour of playing, no leaks were detected, I try to be quite thorough and use convenience methods in cocos2d and cocoa as much as possible, I'm wondering if my repeated use of [NSMutableArray array]; whenever an animation plays, rather than alloc, init, release is causing a back up of data and the autorelease pool isn't firing?

Comment: Have you rebooted your device? Rarely but sometimes odd things occur when you've been running the device without a reboot (only "standby") for a long time. Press and hold the power button and then hold the home button too, hold them for 10+ seconds to force a complete reset of the device (apps and settings aren't removed in case you're worried).

Comment: Thanks Steffen, I did try this but to no avail, after further testing, it does seem like memory is being an issue, I managed to get the iPad to run with allocations and leaks, it seems the allocated memory does climb and climb as I am using my app (until it crashes), but I find no problems in leaks what so ever.

Comment: have to profile your app with Instruments, to find memory leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For consuming less memory. Use the CCTextureCache. Remember that Cocos2D always saves images with a width/height being a power of 2. So if your image is 513 pixels it'll use an image with 1024 pixels.

```
CCTexture2D *texture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"randomImage.png"];
CCSprite *randomImage = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:texture];
```

For saving even more memory you can look into using Texture Atlases. Whenever you switch to a menu or game you can call removeUnusedTextures (or when outofmemory get called).

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
```

You can also use images in a lower quality to save memory.

```
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];
```

Whenever you need to load higher quality images or gradients you can put it back.

```
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
```

Comment: I did not refresh the page before posting my answer, I will however give you the bounty, as this answer would have undoubtedly lead me to the solution.

Comment: I cannot award it for another 21 hours, i will do so tomorrow.

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/31092 - This was also likely to be a massive cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, it sounds as though the memory warning is causing a double-release somewhere.

The first thing to do here is enable Zombie objects. Formerly, you'd set `NSZombieEnabled` in your Target's arguments. More recently, Xcode has added UI support for Zombies. This can be found under:

**Manage Schemes... > Edit... > Diagnostics > Enable Zombie Objects**

This will cause the debugger to breakpoint when it detects that a a released object is being accessed, and should give you a stack trace to help with diagnosis.

When testing in the Simulator, it is possible to generate memory warnings manually. This can be found under:

**iOS Simulator > Hardware > Simulate Memory Warning**

An alternative is to add an action to your UI to simply allocate more memory, which can be used until the crash is triggered. A simple call to `malloc` is sufficient:

```
- (IBAction)simulateMemoryLeak
{
    malloc(1024 * 1024 * 10); // Leak 10MB of memory.
}
```

Instruments crashes are difficult to diagnose, but I've found that a clean re-install of Xcode has fixed Instruments crashing issues for me in the past.

Note that Instruments uses the **Release** configuration to run, whereas normal debugging uses the **Debug** configuration, so do check that you can run under the **Release** configuration normally before attempting to run with Instruments.

Using retina graphics for iPad will take up a large amount of memory, so ensure that you're unloading an `UIImageView` outlets appropriately.

In particular, ensure you understand the [View Controller Lifecycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html) and are unloading view outlets in `viewDidUnload` (called in low memory conditions) and not just `dealloc`.

[image: View Controller Lifecycle]

To help diagnose further, please try to include any more information you can offer on how you're building your menu UI (you state that this is likely the cause of the crash) and how you're doing memory management (use of ARC, use of autorelease pools, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a viewDidUnload method which releases stuff which you still need? This will be called when you get a memory warning, so you have to be careful what you free up. Just use it to free up stuff which is ok to be reloaded when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Google pointed me in the direction of this article.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2361/how-to-create-and-optimize-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-with-texture-packer-and-pixel-formats

Setting various spritesheets to pixel format RGBA4444 seems to have ceased the crashing. I can only assume I was hitting the physical memory limit of the iPad with the sprites I was loading into memory.